# How can I decide to accept incoming connections or not in MacOs firewall?

Tags: macos, firewall

Searching for the keywords "accept incoming connections" in ran into questions asking how to stop the message box *keeping* to pop up. I would rather like to know, quite generally, why application require incoming connections at all.

**How can a normal user decide to accept incoming connections or not? After all, firewalls are a security feature.**

For the question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4499578/do-i-need-to-allow-the-application-stoned-to-accept-incoming-networking-connec ,
one answer given was:

> No, definitely don't allow any app to accept connections if you're
>   unsure.

I don't consider myself a normal user because I have at least some admin knowledge. But still I struggle with that problem. There are several reasons for asking:

- these messages pop up from time to time, seemingly without any cause
- it doesn't seem to make any difference if I accept or not; the applications keeps working
- as far as I understand the inner workings of firewalls, applications on my computer initiate communication to the world themselves, and only *then* the firewall allows communication back to my application. With this view, incoming connections refer not internally initiated communication (right...?). If this is true, I wonder how some external party knows that the application is running on my computer.
- after accepting (or not), the app appears in the firewall rules. Why do I see an exception rule for *not* accepting, instead of only those apps for which I accepted. Seems not to make any sense.

A few minutes ago a got the message to accept incoming connections for timed (time synchronisation daemon, according to man pages). I have never seen this request before; shall I accept ...?